# Automating Excel 2010 using F#

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, excel, f#, excel-2010

I have been searching for a FAQ to tell me how to open a Excel Workbook/Worksheet and also how to Save the File once I have finished.

I notice that in most FAQ and all the books I have purchased on F# one is show how to create a new Workbook/Worksheet but is never shown how to either open or Save it.

Being a newbie to F# I would  very much appreciate it if anyone could kindly provide me with either an answer or perhaps a few pointers?

**Update**

As for why F# and not C# or VB?

I am pleased to say that inspite of being a newbie (with the exception of Forth, VBA & Excel 2003, 2007 & 2010 and Visual Basic) I can do this in both VB, VBA & C# and since I've been retired on medical grounds, with plenty of time unfortunately on my hands, I like to continually set  myself  challenges to keep my little grey cells active and being a sucker for trying new languages....well!

F# is now an intergral part of Visual Studio 2010 so I thought - why not. Consider this - if we are not willing to use or at least try a new languages - I would always be wonder if I might have prefer it to VBA, VB, C# ..... and if you look at it from another point of view, if no one is going to use it - why create it in the first place? I suppose you can say if cave men hadn't experimented and made fire by rubbing two sticks together - where would we be now and would matches have been invented?

Although an complete answer would be good, I prefer a few pointers, to keep my challenge going.

And lastly but not least - thank you for taking the trouble to respond!

Comment: Why F# not standard C# or VB?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think their is a specific F# library for Office, so you will just use the exact same .NET library that you use in VB.NET/C#. F# is a .NET language, so anything that can be done in C# can be done in F# (but you probably already knew that :) ). The API call will be exactly the same, it just that they will be done using the F# syntax instead of the VB/C# one. So for example something that look like this

```
public void SaveMyWorkbook() {
    string filePath = @"C:\failworkbooks\catfail.xlsx";
    workbook.Save(filepath);
}
```

Will be expressed in F# as

```
let filePath = "C:\\failworkbooks\\catfail.xlsx";

let saveWorkbook() = workbook.Save(filePath) |> ignore //if the Save method return something
```

Now, what you will soon realize is that the API isn't exactly designed to be easily used from a functional language. It can be done, but this task in particuliar is much more tailored to C#/VB.NET.

If you really want to enjoy F#, I suggest you use in area where its strength really show. My personal experience is that functional language are awesome when a lot of math is involved. It is also marvellous if you want to easily introduce parallelism in your application (since F# code is usually side effect free). So anything that require data crunching on a lot of data is perfect for it. But for task that consist mainly of putting together a bunch of API call to an external library, F# is kind of meh. You could say that F# is kind of like a graphic card programming language, while C# a general purpose CPU programming language. A lot of thing run better with C#, but the stuff that run better on F# run *really* better on it.

But if you really want to go that route, my suggestion is to try to use the Office API as you already know it, but with a F# syntax. If at some point you really have no idea how to do a *specific* task, ask a question about it on stackoverflow with your code and exactly want you want to do. Those question get answered ridiculously fast compared to broad all-encompassing question, so you won't wait long. (Programmer seem to love precise question with a specific answer ^^)

I hope that it helped a little.

Answer (score 1):

I found this http://iouri-khramtsov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/automating-excel-with-f.html helpful advice.  Briefly, you'd use something like this:

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"  // Assuming it's a script

let excel = ApplicationClass(Visible = true)

let openFileName = @"C:\MyDir\MyFilenameToOpen.xls"
excel.Workbooks.Open(openFileName)

// Do stuff

let savedFileName = @"C:\MyDir\MyFilename.xls"
workbook.SaveAs(savedFileName)
```

Using F# with Excel seems like a natural fit.

Getting to a result in Excel requires the use of several immutable values, each driven by formulas.  Excel has a brilliant user interface, a lovely model of the world - I love rows, columns and cells - but to automate or customise things requires macros.  Why learn this when you can use F#?  Formulas and immutable values are fundamental to its design.

Ideally you'd write formulas yourself as a User Defined Function (UDFs) also in F# - see http://excel-dna.net/ .  Then, perhaps, you'd want to do something interesting with objects/types - Look for "github com mndrake ExcelObjectHandler" (I don't have enough reputation to post a 3rd link).

Jack